# how to upload a image that pasted on rich text box along with contents using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have installed TinyMCE ,but what I want is to copy the image which I pasted on textarea along with the text content by clicking the button and then upload them into another page. I just tried the following code for textarea pageh

```
function processUser()
{
    var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");

    var temp = parameters[0].split("=");
    l = unescape(temp[1]);
    temp = parameters[1].split("=");
    p = unescape(temp[1]);
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = l; 
}

<form name="parameters" method="GET" action="param-received.html" target="_parent">
    <textarea name="log">Hai this is a test msg!!!</textarea>
    <p> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send data">
    </p>
</form>
```

And the link page will be,

```
function addComment() 
{
    var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");

    var temp = parameters[0].split("=");
    l = unescape(temp[1]);

    temp = parameters[1].split("=");
    c = unescape(temp[1]);

    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = l;   
}
addComment();


<form method="get" action="textarea.html">
```

But this will display only the text in the text area along with "+" symbol and doesn't display any images...

Please help me to do this job...

Thanks in advance,
Sandra

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in a fiddle?

Comment: So, if you installed TinyMCE, images must by pasted automatically from clipboard with `<img>` tag. What's your problem now, you don't see it or you can't save it properly?

Comment: I want to paste the whole content along with text and images into another div section